# mongoimport rejects NumberDecimal types

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Mongodb from v.3.4 supports [NumberDecimal](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#numberdecimal)

I have MongoDB server version: **3.4.1**, but when I execute **mongoimport** shell command I get an error:

> Failed: error processing document #7: invalid character 'D' in literal NumberInt or NumberLong (expecting 'I' or 'L')

My json:

```
{"c":"7E474601-B511-4AD9-B2B8-7E61807F9673","n":"n1","v":NumberDecimal("95")}
```

Normal insert executes ok, so this is mongoimort problem.

```
db.aaa.insert({"c":"7E474601-B511-4AD9-B2B8-7E61807F9673","n":"n1","v":NumberDecimal("95")})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

Why is that? Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One trick to figure out the correct [extended json](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) format is to use the mongoexport utility on a collection to see how MongoDB itself publishes the json out.

In this case the following should work:

`{"c":"7E474601-B511-4AD9-B2B8-7E61807F9673","n":"n1","v":{"$numberDecimal":"95"}}`

I tested this with mongoimport with server version 3.4.1 and it imports the numberDecimal correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`NumberDecimal("95")` is not a valid [JSON](http://json.org/) representation. It should be

```
{"c":"7E474601-B511-4AD9-B2B8-7E61807F9673","n":"n1","v":95}
```

It works with mongo shell because the shell is a javascript interpreter that treats `NumberDecimal` as a valid data type.

If you need `NumberDecimal` data type you need to use a driver or the mongo shell.

Form a bash shell you can run this simple script:

```
for i in `cat aaa.json`
do
 mongo --quiet --eval "db.aaa.insert($i)"
done
```

Please note that this is row by row insertion and not very efficient.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I want this number to be stored as NumberDecimal, not as default Double. "v":95 will save as double. The normal shell db.aaa.insert from the example, inserts properly as NumberDecimal. I will also have values such as 9999999.99999999999999 so I need NumericDecimal

Comment: `mongoimport`, when running against a JSON file automatically, detects the data type as per JSON spec. If you want `NumberDecimal`, then you need to use mongo shell or a driver.

Comment: Ok, so NumberInt and NumberLong are in json spec, yes? I am asking because, as you see in exception, mongoimport suggests me to use them. So they should be ok. But why NumericDecimal is unsupported. I suppose it will change in future, NumberDecimal is new I hope they will update mongoimport soon.

Comment: @Barney: JSON only has one type of numbers and that's `number`. MongoDB uses extended json ([Jai's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41882662/2965883)). I believe that support for NumberLong will be added for mongoimport in future releases.